# Django default data (Fixtures?) in views.py on form.save()?

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

Wondering what would be the best approach  in Django to insert some default DB data every time a new account is created with `form.save()`.

Lets say the user just created a new business profile account and I would like to pre-load data that are customized with the new business ID and today's dates right after the `form.save()` (so I have the new account IDs available).

Obviously, I can use the hard coded approach and write 10 lines of `Model.objects.create(...)` and be done with it but I was wondering what would be the "correct" Django/pythonic way of doing this through something like JSON fixture file etc.

Comment: Fixture files are for testing.

Comment: Any suggestions @DanielRoseman how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is only creating an id, you can have a model with null allowed fields and auto id field. Other fields can also have default values. default field option also allows callbacks. 
ex:-

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Look at:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#field-options

A Model with all nullable fields or default value fields can essentially be created with a single line of code in form.save(). Assuming you intend to create a single default model object only.

As for the right way, you might want to have simple flags(to record an business profile as active leaving the default one inactive etc.) in your model and right relationships(FK) so that a user cannot repeatedly create default business profiles.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, this is not about only setting a today's date as I need to be able to add other variables. BTW for the dates, I usually use `auto_now_add=True`

Comment: auto_now_add=True seems better than using default=datetime.now for dates. I just wanted to convey the possibility of having callbacks  for default value. The callbacks can have any type of complex logic to reach a default value for a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a django post_save signal. Its easy to use.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

You can put the code in models.py of that application itself.

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=ModelName)
def do_some_operation(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:                 # Executes only if created 
        obj = kwargs['instance']
        # do modifications with your obj
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out!